# Detect element inside div in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im thinking about way to detect a element index when this element is inside of some other element.
[image]

So red box is my div, black box is centered absolute in center of this div. 1,2,3 are the list element. How to detect on scroll when list element is inside of black div?

Comment: see: [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Comment: In React, you probably want to create [Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) for each of your list items and for the black box element, in order to be able to refer to their widths, heights and X/Y positions.

Comment: Yea, i wan't to create some kind of flatlist but in basic react not native. Is this possible with intersection API?